# How can I change the timezone of a column in Apache Nifi?

Tags: timezone, utc, apache-nifi

We use Apache Nifi for our data ingestion. 
We extract data from multiple sources, especially oracle databases. A lot of the extracted tables contain timestamps. As we are working in an international context, I want to change the timezone of all the timestamps into UTC time.

- how can I change  the timezone of a timestamp column into UTC time?
- is there a generic solution, so that all timestamps are converted at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can able to convert timestamp column into UTC time.

Please look at below reference website.
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#format

Just consider you are having attribute named "time" which having value `1420058163264`

```
${time:format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "GMT")}
```

In format method you can pass your timezone which can convert timestamp into UTC Timezone.

I hope that it helps/

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I already found out that I can use expression language to change the format, but which type of processor do I have to use? And is there a generic method to format all the columns at once?

Comment: I think no other processor which formats all columns at once.You may try ExecuteScript Or Custom processor